# Browsers hear onclick BEFORE onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would need any "click" to run only AFTER the browser check if there was any change to the form ('onchange'). Is it possible?

For example:

```html
    <input type="text" onchange="alert('CHANGED!')">
    <a href="javascript:alert('CLICKED!')">click here</a>
```

After changing the input element above, when I click on the link, the onclick event is always called before the input onchange event. Can you reverse this?

Comment: Instead of `onchange`, use `oninput`.

Comment: You sure you changed something in the input first? What browser are you seeing this in? Can not reproduce in chrome or firefox

Comment: onchange isn't called when the browser checks for a change, it's called when a change occurs.

Answer (score -1):

You can cancel the native `click` event and defer what should happen until after the change event gets a chance to run by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Also, note that you should not be using inline HTML event attributes these days. Instead, follow modern standards as described in the comments below.

```js
// Get references to your DOM elements
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var link = document.querySelector("a");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not in HTML
input.addEventListener("change", function(){ alert("changed"); });
link.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<a href="#">click here</a>
```

Comment: Can you even reproduce OP's problem?